# How can I speed up DataColumn check?

Tags: c#, datatable

```
string specifiedSymbol = "MySymbol";

Systems.Data.DataTable table = CreateInitialTable();

if (!table.Columns.Contains(specifiedSymbol))
       table.Columns.Add(specifiedSymbol, Type.GetType("System.Double"));
```

I have just profiled the above statment and it seems that the IF takes around 10ms. This is a long time for my app. How else could I check if a column exists in datatable more efficiently?

Comment: table.Enumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("Column Name" == "abc").Select(.....)

Comment: How many columns do you have?! And if you have a method for creating a table, why do you need to check what columns it returns? Does it return different columns every time?

Comment: How did you know the if statement was taking 10 ms?  How could that feel too long to a user?

Answer (score 0):

It's not obvious what classes or imports you are using, so I will provide a generic answer.

When calling `Contains()` on a collection which has O(n) complexity (or worse), performance can be improved by doing one of the following:

- Manage a separate `HashSet` in which you mirror any changes made to the O(n) collection, then use the `Contains()`-method of the `HashSet` to test for presence.
- If you cannot track the changes to your collection, you may still be able to improve performance by creating a `HashSet` and filling it with the contents of the collection every time you need to call `Contains()` **iff** you need to call it multiple times in a row, i.e. without intermittent change-operations and the time lost using the collection's implementation taking longer than creating a new `HashSet` from its contents entirely. This is less desirable than the former for performance reasons, but more desirable for code-manageability.

The best case scenario is being able to write a new class which inherits from the collection's class and putting all the logic in there.